# Remove the empty lines of particular part in number of files in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++, I need a plugin for removing `empty lines` for particular part only. We have one plugin that is `TextFX`. But that plugin works very well. But I need to remove the empty lines from selecting particular area only in number of files.

Can anyone suggest me one plugin.

Comment: See point 4 in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about a plugin, but you can search/replace for empty lines like this:

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Select the particular area
- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^$\R`
- **Replace With:** (nothing)
- Check **regular expression**
- Check **In selection**
- Click Replace All

**Explanation**
* `^$\R` is a regular expression matching empty lines inlcuding the newline charactar

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to remove lines of particular area of the file only. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes: as described in the first bullet point: **Select the particular area** and use **In selection** as described in the sixth bullet point.